# Detect if an object has a specific colour out of 3 colours using opencv (cv2 in python3)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, color-detection, python

I am currently working on a program that can detect if a red object is kept in my room or is is there a blue object. The rest of my surroundings is either white or black. I have tried to minimize the variation of light in my room.

I have successfully created a mask around the object given a certain hue range. I want my program to print for me :

1) "Red"- If there is a red object

2) "Blue"- If there is a blue object

I don't know how to proceed. Following is my program that cretes the mask around the object that is blue. I have given the hue range of a few other colours also. So that you can try it.

The program:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    _, frame = cam.read()

    denoised = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (31, 31), 35)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(denoised, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)


    lower_blue = np.array([110, 50, 50])
    upper_blue = np.array([160, 255, 255])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    #cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
    cv2.imshow('res', res)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Hue of different colours (I am not sure about the hue of red because it doesn't work for some colours- I have tried a few solutions from Stackoverflow):

```
lower_red = np.array([0, 100, 100])
upper_red = np.array([0, 255, 255])

lower_yellow = np.array([15, 210, 20])
upper_yellow = np.array([35, 255, 255])

lower_green = np.array([29, 86, 6])
upper_green = np.array([64, 255, 2555])

lower_orange = np.array([10, 100, 20])
upper_orange = np.array([20,255,255])
```

Following are some sample images that you can experiment with:

[image: Blue Image]

[image: Red Image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is correct in a way. But to determine the color of a specific region of the image, you need to calculate the Euclidean distance between the known dataset of the colors and the L*a*b averages of the region.

1. Detect a specific region of interest, for which you need the color.
2. Refer the following code to determine the color within the region of interest.

   ```
   class ColorLabeler:
       def __init__(self):
           # initialize the colors dictionary, containing the color
           # name as the key and the RGB tuple as the value
           colors = OrderedDict({
               "red": (255, 0, 0),
               "green": (0, 255, 0),
               "blue": (0, 0, 255)})

           # allocate memory for the L*a*b* image, then initialize
           # the color names list
           self.lab = np.zeros((len(colors), 1, 3), dtype="uint8")
           self.colorNames = []

           # loop over the colors dictionary
           for (i, (name, rgb)) in enumerate(colors.items()):
               # update the L*a*b* array and the color names list
               self.lab[i] = rgb
               self.colorNames.append(name)

           # convert the L*a*b* array from the RGB color space
           # to L*a*b*
           self.lab = cv2.cvtColor(self.lab, cv2.COLOR_RGB2LAB)

   def label(self, image, c):
       # construct a mask for the contour, then compute the
       # average L*a*b* value for the masked region
       mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")
       cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, 255, -1)
       mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
       mean = cv2.mean(image, mask=mask)[:3]

       # initialize the minimum distance found thus far
       minDist = (np.inf, None)

       # loop over the known L*a*b* color values
       for (i, row) in enumerate(self.lab):
           # compute the distance between the current L*a*b*
           # color value and the mean of the image
           d = dist.euclidean(row[0], mean)

           # if the distance is smaller than the current distance,
           # then update the bookkeeping variable
           if d < minDist[0]:
               minDist = (d, i)

       # return the name of the color with the smallest distance
       return self.colorNames[minDist[1]]
   ```

   - The above code is borrowed from PyImageSearch and, for your reference, the full blog post can be found here : (https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/15/determining-object-color-with-opencv/)